# How do I get intellisense for WCF Ajax Services?

Tags: javascript, ajax, visual-studio-2008, wcf, intellisense

I've finally got Intellisense working for JQuery by applying patch KB958502 to Visual Studio 2008 and including this line:

```
/// <reference path="JQuery\jquery-1.3.2.js"/>
```

at the top of my .js files.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to get JavaScript intellisense for the client proxies generated by the ScriptManager's ScriptReference elements (as shown here):

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="Server" EnablePartialRendering="false" AsyncPostBackTimeout="999999">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference path="../Services/DocLookups.svc" />
        </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

The client proxies are working -- i.e. I can make calls through them, but I'm getting no Intellisense.

My service is defined with a .svc file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Documents.Services.DocLookups" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/DocLookups.cs" %>
```

The code behind file looks like:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "Documents.Services", Name = "DocLookups")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class DocLookups {
...
```

a sample method in this class is:

```
    //Called at the begining of the page to fill in the category list
    [OperationContract]
    public SelectOption[] GetCategoriesForSelectList()
    {
        SelectOption[] Result;
        IDocumentRepository repository = new DocumentEntityRepository(ConnectionString);
        Result = (from cat in repository.GetDocCategories()
                  select new SelectOption(cat.Category_ID.ToString(), cat.CategoryName)).ToArray();
        if (Result.Length > 0)
            Result[0].Selected = true;  //Select first item 
        return Result;
    }
```

and it uses a data contract defined like this:

```
namespace Documents.Services {

[DataContract]
public class SelectOption
{
    //A useful DTO to use when filling a <select> element with options
    public SelectOption(string optionValue, string optionText) {
        OptionValue = optionValue;
        OptionText = optionText;
        Selected = false;
    }
    public SelectOption(string optionValue, string optionText, bool selected) {
        OptionValue = optionValue;
        OptionText = optionText;
        Selected = selected;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string OptionValue { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string OptionText { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

}

In my javascript files, a call to this service looks like:

```
Documents.Services.DocLookups.GetCategoriesForSelectList(...
```

but I get no Intellisense (for example, if I type Documents. nothing pops up).  I don't get intellisense for either the generated methods or the [DataContract] types used by the methods.

I believe that I am **supposed** to get Intellisense for these proxies and types, but can't figure out what I might be doing wrong.  TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did 
`/// <reference path="../Services/DocLookups.svc" />` 
not work?

Comment: It didn't work initially, as I indicated in my post, but it DID work once I realized I had to preceed it with a ref to MicrosoftAjax.js

/// <reference name="MicrosoftAjax.js" />
/// <reference path="../Documents/Services/DocLookups.svc" />

So thanks for the help.

Comment: /// <reference path="http://localhost/Services/DocLookups.svc/js" /> .....wouldn't that be nice!

Comment: Preceding the service file reference with the MicrosoftAjax.js reference is apparently also required in VS2010.  I could not find that documented anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Scott for pointing out that I need to add the

```
///<reference path...
```

line.  I don't know where it's documented but I somehow missed that this was required for the WCF generated client-side proxies -- although it makes sense now given the same idiom is used to get the Intellisense for JQuery.

For the record, the line I ended up having to use was slightly different than what Scott suggested given my projects structure.  I tried:

```
/// <reference path="../Documents/Services/DocLookups.svc" />
```

I then saved the file and from the VS Edit menu chose **Intellisense**... **Update JScript Intellisense**...

Unfortunately, this did not work and I got the following error when updating the Intellisense:

```
Error updating JScript IntelliSense: 
C:\TFSSource\LitigationPortal\Version 1.0\LitigationPortal\Documents\Services\DocLookups.svc:
'Type' is undefined @ 0:0
```

So I've made some progress but I'm not quite there yet.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same problem and found that there's a hotfix for Visual Studio 2008 available that solved my issue:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958502